# Django 'long' object has no attribute 'member'

Tags: python, django, authentication, tastypie

I'm trying to handle an exception that's being thrown when users try to login through my Tastypie API, but I'm not sure I have the syntax correct.

```
def login(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.method_check(request, allowed = ['post'])

    data = self.deserialize(request, request.body, format = request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))

    username = data.get('email', '')
    password = data.get('password', '')
    print username
    #print password

    user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
    #member = user.member
    #print user 

    if user:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            user = user.id

            try:
                print 'user has member'
                member = user.member.id
                return self.create_response(request, {'success' : True, 'member' : member})
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                print 'user does not have member'
                return self.create_response(request, {'success' : True, 'member' : False})




        else:
            return self.create_response(request, {'success' : False, 'reason' : 'disabled'}, HttpForbidden)
    else:
        return self.create_response(request, {'success' : False, 'reason' : 'incorrect'}, HttpUnauthorized)
```

The error is given at `member = user.member.id` in the `try`.

```
member = user.member.id\n\nAttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'member'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line overwrites `user` with `id` attribute value; `user` now reference `long` object; causes AttributeError.

```
    user = user.id
```

Remove the line.